# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable in AES Algorithm using Python

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, aes, ecb

I want to encrypt a text using `AES` algorithm. The code is given below.But when I run this code, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/a/AES/aes.py", line 159, in <module>
cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf8'), AES.MODE_ECB)
  File "/home/a/anaconda3/envs/AES/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 232, in new
return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/a/anaconda3/envs/AES/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)
  File "/home/a/anaconda3/envs/AES/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ecb.py", line 216, in _create_ecb_cipher
cipher_state = factory._create_base_cipher(kwargs)
  File "/home/a/anaconda3/envs/AES/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 92, in _create_base_cipher
if len(key) not in key_size:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

code :

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad

key = 'QwroeApp90652321'
AES.key_size=128
AES.block_size=128
plaintext = "wdrdooloo"
cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf8'), AES.MODE_ECB)
msg =cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext.encode('utf8'), 16))
print(msg.hex())
```

I want to encrypt the text with `128` bit key size , `128` bit block size , `PKCS7` padding and in `ECB` mode.

Can anyone suggest a solution to solve this issue.

Comment: ```AES.key_size=(128)```

Comment: I am not getting the correct output.Still I am getting the same error when I used your code.@Zhubei Federer

Comment: I just reminder the type of ```AES.key_size``` must can't be int, are you sure the TypeError is still in key_size?

Comment: yes@Zhubei Federer

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the following lines:

```py
AES.key_size=128
AES.block_size=128
```

because they overwrite the parameters of the `AES` module of the `pyCryptodome` library ([look at the source code](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/180d9d3a2740b18ce56bf4b81374f483b875607d/lib/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py#L247), lines 246 - 250).

If you remove them, the code works as expected, producing the following output:

```bash
4742782fa8cb2be804b91d25e815765d
```

Comment: Yes I got the same output when removing the same lines of code.But I want to fix the key size as 128 , block size as 128 and padding as `PKCS7`. In the decryption part, key size and block size is mentioned as 128 and padding as `pkcs7`@PieCot

Comment: The code is reasoning in bytes. Look at the source code: `key_size` is expressed in bytes, so using a key that is 16 bytes, you are using a key of 128 bits. Moreover, if you look again at the source code, the `block_size` is set at 16 bytes, so again 128 bits.